# Replace text from jquery loaded external html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I used this code to load content from another html file:

```
<script> 
    $(function(){
      $("#includedContent").load("reslist.html"); 
    });
</script>


<div id="includedContent"></div>
```

The reslist.html contents this script:

```
<div id="sub-menu-column" align="left"><h2>
     Smith Residence<br />
     Smith Pool<br />
     Fis Residence<br />
     Res Residence
</h2></div>
```

It loads correctly into my page. 
But now: How do I replace a string from loaded content? Because I want to load the text "Smith Residence" in a red colored font.

Comment: Will it *always* say "Smith Residence", or will that change?

Comment: On every page another title will be red. So the text is fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `.load()` callback function, this will replace the text in question with a span containing the text, that you can then alter using css...

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $("#includedContent").load("reslist.html", function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Smith Residence", "<span class='red'>Smith Residence</span>"));
    }); 
});
```

**CSS**

```
.red {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Archer, this was exactly what I was searching for!

Answer (score 0):

you can use an ajax call instead of the .load function and replace the text you want before appending it to the container.

For example:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  url: "reslist.html",
  success: function(data) {
    data = data.replace(/(Smith Residence)/, "<span style='color: red;'>$1</span>");
    jQuery("#includedContent").html(data);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps,

Regards,

Marcelo

Comment: I couldn't let this work Mindastic. But the other answer was exactly what I was searching for. Thank you